# Angularjs ng-repeat filtered by one property, property duplicate issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to filter my array by teams and show all players in each team, but if the name of the team is similar eg. 'team beta' and 'team beta z' duplicate problem occures.
Player is shown in both teams...

here is example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/lukasz9999/qpqsuvc5/1/

I think problem lays in filtering method

```
<div ng-repeat="playerPerTeam in playersToFilter() | filter:filterTeams">
   <b>{{playerPerTeam.team}}</b>

<li ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{team: playerPerTeam.team} | filter:searchFilter">{{player.name}}</li>        
</div>


$scope.players = [{name: 'Gene', team: 'team alpha'},
                {name: 'George', team: 'team beta'},
                {name: 'Steve', team: 'team gamma'},
                {name: 'Paula', team: 'team beta'},
                {name: 'Paula2', team: 'team beta z'},
                {name: 'Scruath of the 5th sector', team: 'team gamma'}];



var indexedTeams = [];

$scope.playersToFilter = function() {
    indexedTeams = [];
    return $scope.players;

}

$scope.filterTeams = function(player) {

    var teamIsNew = indexedTeams.indexOf(player.team) == -1;
    console.log("nt "+teamIsNew)
    if (teamIsNew) {
        indexedTeams.push(player.team);
    }
    return teamIsNew;
}
```

- this code produces this list:
- team alpha

  - Gene
- team beta

  - George
  - Paula
  - Paula2
- team gamma

  - Steve
  - Scruath of the 5th sector
- team beta z

  - Paula2

name: Paula2 should be only in "team beta z" but is in "team beta" as well.

thank you for any advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `true` just after the filter statement would do the trick. So,

```
filter:{team: playerPerTeam.team}
```

should be

```
filter:{team: playerPerTeam.team}:true
```

for exact match. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

You can see the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dV9QwD13Jm9ud9w0E1ml?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `track by $index` at the end of the ng-repeat="" that you use.

By doing this, angular identifies the elements with their index in the array, instead of their value.

Example:

`ng-repeat="playerPerTeam in playersToFilter() | filter:filterTeams track by $index"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it sounds really good, but I don't know why it doesn,t work. new version with track by index https://jsfiddle.net/lukasz9999/qpqsuvc5/2/